# Selenium Java: Cannot use jquery, getting Reference Error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium within Java.

When I want to execute JQuery code, than I am getting an exception.

```
Exception in thread main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I am using GeckDriver and the element which I want to change is a hidden element.

```
driver.executeScript(String.format("return $('#validator').val('%s');", value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Error means that `JQuery` is not defined on your resource (site doesn't use it, so you can't access `$` variable).

As a workaround you can use native JS function.

```java
driver.executeScript(String.format("return document.querySelector('#validator').value = '%s'", value));
```